# How can we get GroovyRowResult to just list values, and not the column headers? Or get just the values in the .gsp view?

Tags: grails, groovy

We are trying to cleanup a groovy sql.rows result to only contain the values that come back from the query.

The query service is pretty straight forward

```
def getRowsFromDB(String sqlStatement) {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(-redacted-)
    def rows = sql.rows (sqlStatement)
    return rows
}
```

The list comes back like:

```
[SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE:SOCI, SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB:291, SCBCRSE_TITLE:Special Topics]
[SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE:SOCI, SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB:306, SCBCRSE_TITLE:Sociology of Work]
[SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE:SOCI, SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB:308, SCBCRSE_TITLE:Soc of Education]
[SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE:SOCI, SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB:312, SCBCRSE_TITLE:Criminal Adjudication]
[SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE:SOCI, SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB:314, SCBCRSE_TITLE:Extraordinary Group Behavior]
```

But we'd like to have it like:

```
SOCI 291 Special Topics
SOCI 306 Sociology of Work
SOCI 308 Soc of Education
SOCI 312 Criminal Adjucation
SOCI 314 Extraordinary Group Behavior
```

Is this something that could easily be done? I tried to add `.value` to the .gsp tag but it throws an error saying no method found.

And finally when I do use this in my views there is always a set of `{ }` wrapping around each item in the list, how do you get rid of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could transform your list of GroovyRowResults into a list of Strings before returning them to the Gsp:

```
return rows.collect {
    "${it.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE} ${it.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB} ${it.SCBCRSE_TITLE}"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

And if you do not want the result as `String` but a list to iterate over and have control over in the view then use:

```
rows.collect{it.values()}
```

should give you

```
[[SOCI, 291, Special Topics], 
 [SOCI, 306, Sociology of Work], 
 [SOCI, 308, Soc of Education], 
 [SOCI, 312, Criminal Adjudication], 
 [SOCI, 314, Extraordinary Group Behavior]]
```